# How can I wait for a method that doesn't return a Future?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter, async-await, dart-async

I am building a screen in an app using an existing model class which I can't modify. The model has a method called `refreshList()` which fetches some data from an API, processes it, and finally it updates a `List` member in a model with the fetched data.

I want to know the state of the list - i.e. is it uninitialized, being fetched or already fetched - so that I can update the UI accordingly.

The problem is that `refreshList()` is not `async`, but uses an `async` method internally. Additionally, the internal method doesn't return a `Future`.

```
void refreshList(){
    if( someCondition ){
        _doRefreshList();
    }
}

void _doRefreshList() async{
    // ... do stuff 

    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    // ... do some more stuff
}
```

I would like to do something like

```
setState((){ _isLoading = true; });
await model.refreshList(); 
setState((){ _isLoading = false; });
```

but unfortunately I can't modify the methods in the model to return a `Future`.

Is there any way to achieve this without modifying `refreshList()` to be `async` and return a `Future`, and modifying `_doRefreshList()` to return a `Future`?

Comment: Why would you not just make it `async`? I doubt that there is another way.

Comment: you can use a Completer to force the method returns a Future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to wait for an asynchronous operation to complete unless *it* provides some way to get a callback when it's done. 
The usual way to do that is to return a future. Having a callback function parameter is another approach, but it's rarely better than just returning a future.

In your example, `refreshVerList` has no way to report when it is done, and neither does `_doRefreshList`. You will have to add that *somehow*, and returning a future is the simplest and most consistent way to solve the problem for both functions.

(Technically, the `_doRefreshList` function does return a future, it's just typed as `void`. You can cast that future to `Future`, but I *strongly* discourage that kinds of shenanigans. If the function author decides to return something else, say `null`, at a later point, they are perfectly within their right to do since the return type is `void`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Completer.

```
Completer<Null> onFetchCompleter;

 Future<Null> _doRefreshList() async{
 onFetchCompleter = Completer();
// ... do stuff 

 http.Response response = await http.get(url);

// ... do some more stuff
 onFetchCompleter.complete();

 return onFetchCompleter.future;
}
```

In the same way you can user a completer in your refreshVerList method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Future` with the function reference as argument:

```
Future(model.refreshList);
```

Now you can use `await` since the above gives you a  `Future<void>`:

```
setState(() { _isLoading = true; });
await Future(model.refreshList);
setState(() { _isLoading = false; });
```